# how to use a method from binding library into Xamarin iOS project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I want to bind my iOS (Objective C) static library into XamariniOS so as per your documentation I have created a binding library project in xamarin studio and bind my ".a" file into binding project. I have also created .dll file and ApiDefination file using Objective Sharpie.I have created an xamarin iOS SingleView Application project and imported the library project and also add reference to the project.Now I want to call a method "void SetupWithId (int Id, string Key) " from my library in when the app goes Active in AppDelegate.cs so it should be call in OnActivated function and other method "void FetchUserDetails (string mobile)" inside ViewDidLoad. My ApiDefination code is as follows:

```
using System;
using UIKit;
using Foundation;
using ObjCRuntime;
using CoreGraphics;

namespace MyLibrarySDK
{
    // @interface IMyLibrary : NSObject
    [BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
    interface MyLibrary
    {
        // @property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer * setupCompleteTimer;
        [Export ("setupCompleteTimer", ArgumentSemantic.Strong)]
        NSTimer SetupCompleteTimer { get; set; }

        // +(void)setupWithId:(int)Id Key:(NSString *)Key;
        [Static]
        [Export ("setupWithId:Key:")]
        void SetupWithId (int Id, string Key);

        // +(void)fetchSettings;
        [Static]
        [Export ("fetchSettings")]
        void FetchSettings ();

        // +(void)fetchUserDetails:(NSString *)mobile;
        [Static]
        [Export ("fetchUserDetails:")]
        void FetchUserDetails (string mobile);
}
```

Note: I have also imported namespace "MyLibrarySDK" inside AppDeligate.cs and created an object for my library also my AppDeligate.cs File is as follows:

```
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using MyLibrarySDK;

namespace TestiOSProject
{

    [Register ("AppDelegate")]
    public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        // class-level declarations

        public  MyLibrary mylib;

        public override UIWindow Window {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override void OnResignActivation (UIApplication application)
        {
        }

        public override void DidEnterBackground (UIApplication application)
        {   
        }

        public override void WillEnterForeground (UIApplication application)
        {   
        }

        public override void OnActivated (UIApplication application)
        {
            mylib = new MyLibrary();

        }
        public override void WillTerminate (UIApplication application)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

till the above code there is no error in my project now I want to execute the above mentioned method. How can I do this Please help me to do it.

Thanks for the same.

Comment: mylib = new MyLibrary(); mylib.SetupWithId(Id, Key);

Comment: Thanks Gusman Its work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public override void OnActivated (UIApplication application)
{
    mylib = new MyLibrary();
    mylib.SetupWithId(parameter1IntValue, "parameter2StringValue");    
}
```

As per Gusman comment the above is worked for me.